# How can I discard the five leading zeroes in my match?

Tags: regex, digit

I need support for my regex. Let's say I have the string `000001234567` where `1234567` is a variable string of digits. I need to extract first five digits starting after the leading 5 zeroes.

Result should be:

```
12345
```

If I use the simple regex `(\d{5})` I get the first 5 digits from left, but I wish to start my capture only after zeroes and get the result `12345`.

Comment: @RNar 1. Your regex is invalid; you've got an extra parenthesis in there somewhere. 2. Reliance on capture groups can be necessary, but your suggestion results in *$&* being equal to "0000012345"; you have to interrogate the first capture group (e.g. *$1*) to get the correct answer.

Comment: i misread the question, thinking that he only wanted 5 digits of the numbers so that is my bad.

Comment: Also, the previous regex finds all possible ways jumping to the right digit by digit, meaning result
12345
23456
34567
Is there any way to keep bounderies on the left and avoid jumping through all variations?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language you're using this might differ slightly but in Ruby:

```
/0+(\d+)/
```

This will give you a match group of `1234567`

Answer (score 1):

Every regex engine is a little different in the features it supports. Your question currently contains no language or engine tags.

One way to solve this with Perl-compatible regular expressions in Perl, Ruby, or pcregrep is to use range modifiers and the "keep" operator. For example, in Ruby:

```
str = '000001234567'
str.match /0{5}\K\d{,5}/
#=> #<MatchData "12345">
```

Other solutions can involve capture groups, negated character classes, zero-width lookbehinds, or other engine-specific features. Not all features are available in all engines, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `0*([1-9]\d{4})` will skip leading zeros, look for one non-zero digit and then four more of any digit.

Having the `[1-9]` in the expression ensures that the first captured digit is not a zero.